# UPDATE sem alterar a data de um registro

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para alterar um registro na minha tabela e manter a data em que o registro foi criado.

No `INSERT` estou usando o método `now()`. Quando eu uso um `UPDATE` para alterar apenas uma coluna a data tá sendo alterada, e eu preciso manter a data em que o registro foi criado, testei primeiro no `phpMyAdmin` e depois na minha aplicação, das duas maneiras a data está sendo alterada.

Comment: Como está sendo feito o `UPDATE` e como está definida a coluna?

Comment: "UPDATE pedidos SET status='$status' WHERE id = '$id'"; A coluna data está com o tipo: timestamp. No meu caso estou precisando atualizar apenas a coluna "status".

Comment: E qual coluna está sendo atualizada junto e deveria manter a data de criação, como mencionou?

Comment: A coluna "data" estava sendo atualizada e alterando a data de criação do registro sendo que eu só queria alterar o "status", mas já foi resolvido com a dica do @William Novak.

Answer (score 3):

Sua tabela deve ter uma coluna com o atributo:

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Remova o atributo da coluna e qualquer atualização na sua tabela não será alterada a data/hora na coluna.

Comment: Opa, deu certo cara, valeu!